# Showing a series is some range

Tags: summation

Hello I am having some issues trying to show the following series is in the range between 60 and 150

I have to use a non-integral method to show the following.

$60 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{32} \lg(k) \leq 150 $

Also I am not allowed to actually evaluate the summation.

I am just lost as to how to actually approach this problem, not sure if I should use some kind of proof method or not.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the base of this logarithm, is it $e$ or $10$ or... ? By the way this is not quite a series, it is a finite sum.

Comment: lg is log base 2

Answer (score 0):

Use that

$\lg(a) + \lg(b) = \lg(ab)$

Thus the sum becomes $\lg (32!)$

Then I guess you need to make a few "smart" observations to obtain these bounds.

Comment: I tried that before and used the sterling approximation but thats apparently wrong because they are looking for upper and lower bound